# Sending localStorage data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I've done some research and even have a book that explains Ajax calls to php and sending data to and from browser and server. I found this to be pretty close to what I need since I am using local storage [How can I pass saved localStorage web data to a php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042565/how-can-i-pass-saved-localstorage-web-data-to-a-php-script), this link seems pretty coherent but I am not sure what to do on the PHP side [How to pass data from Javascript to PHP and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406316/how-to-pass-data-from-javascript-to-php-and-vice-versa),

though I have a bigger problem, the amount of data I have in local storage is pretty large, there are several different arrays that are stored there and are JSON encoded, when I get the array I use JSON.parse and to set the array in storage I stringify it. How could this be done to send that kind of data over? Not all the data in localStorage is an array either, there are hundreds of variables in local storage that need to be saved.

EDIT:

Here is my code since it was brought to my attention that it is needed. 
I am trying to get all the data from localstorage to be sent to the server to be saved in a database.

```
function postData(){

    var storage = JSON.stringify(localStorage);

    var xhr;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open('POST', 'Membership.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type: text/json", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("data=" + storage);

}
```

On the PHP side of things I have

```
if ($_POST){

    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

    echo "The data" .$data;

}
```

I don't know if this is correct, I can't find anything on how to pass all localstorage data, this is basically what I was trying to ask before but obviously failed to convey that.

Comment: A great way to send data (some or lots) from Javascript to PHP is in a JSON encoded object. Why not just dump your entire localStorage into a JSON object, use AJAX to send that to PHP then use PHP to `json_decode()` the object? In answer to your question on how to access it in PHP, you'd use either `$_GET['var_name']` or `$_POST[]` depending on the HTTP method you use. Beyond this, you'll need to provide some examples of what you've tried for us to help further.

Comment: I figured my post would get down voted, I am a beginner and it seems like stack overflow is just not a beginner-friendly environment, I tried my best to ask a question. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: If I have the params set in javascript to be
var json = localStorage.getItem(sessionKey);
params = "data=" + JSON.stringify(json) + "";` I don't even know if this is correct, I'll try it but I think this is what you are saying right? (This is on the JS side) params is what I send using Ajax .send method

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do is:

1. Retrieve all the data from localStorage
2. Stringify everything (Now you have JSON representation of all the data)
3. Prepare the AJAX request using jQuery or other_framework_of_choice and set the payload to the stringified data and send it:

   - Send `Content-type: text/json` ti send a hint to the service that you are sending JSON data (Optional, but recommended)
4. Process the data within the PHP side (I.e `json_decode`the payload and process it using your own logic satisfying your needs.

### NOTE:

You didn't provided any code, so I would just skip the coding part (I can't guess your codes, mate)

### EDIT

You can refer to [Send data from localStorage via AJAX to PHP and save it in an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336996/send-data-from-localstorage-via-ajax-to-php-and-save-it-in-an-html-file?rq=1) 
just skip the saving part and replace with your desired processing

Comment: 3, 4 and the first part of 5 are all the same thing.

Comment: Thinking about it, You are right. Will edit it to reflect actual steps (Thanks for pointing it out tho)

Comment: Now you're missing the PHP part :) </nitpick>

Comment: Lol let me try one more time :p. How is it now

Comment: So what you mean is JSON.stringify(localStorage); ?

Comment: Well not exactly. Extract the data which you need in to a separate variable(I doubt that you need to convert the whole localData object.) in the same way you are creating it for use in javascript